# Getting error during compiling java program

Tags: java

I have below two classes

```
import java.util.*;
public interface Stack<Item> extends Iterable<Item>{
    void push(Item item);
    Item pop();
    boolean isEmpty();
    int size();
    Iterator<Item> iterator();
}
```

Second class is the :

```
import java.util.*;
public class LinkedStack<Item> implements Stack<Item>{

private Node head;
private int size;


private class Node{
    Item item;
    Node next;

    public Node(Item item){
        this.item = item;

    }

    public Node(Item item, Node next){
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;

    }
}


public boolean isEmpty(){
    return(head == null);
}

public int size(){
    return size;
}

public void push(Item item){
    head = new Node(item,head);
    size++;
}   

public Item pop(){
    Item item = head.item;
    head = head.next;
    size--;
    return item;
}

public Iterator<Item> iterator(){
    return new LinkedStackIterator<Item>();
}

class LinkedStackIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item>{
    private Node current = head;

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return current != null;
    }

    public Item next(){
        Item return_item = current.item;
        current = current.next;
        return return_item;
    }

    public void remove(){};
}
}
```

I am getting typecast error in method `public Item next()`:

```
Item return_item = current.item;
```

If I write above line as

```
Item return_item = (Item) current.item;
```

It works fine. Can anybody suggest the reason?

I am getting below compilation error:

> LinkedStack.java:57: error: incompatible types
>    Item return_item = current.item;
>                              ^
>    required: Item#2
>    found:    Item#1
>    where Item#1,Item#2 are type-variables:
>      Item#1 extends Object declared in class LinkedStack
>      Item#2 extends Object declared in class LinkedStack.LinkedStackIterator
>   1 error

Comment: What's the type of `current.item`?

Comment: @Christian I suppose it's of type Item.

Comment: If it were of type `Item` you won't need to cast it. Look at that class or its documentation to see what type it returns. Check also if `Item` implements any *interface*. There may be the answer.

Comment: They're different `Item` types. You need to either make `Node` generic or make `LinkedStackIterator` not generic. My vote is to make `Node` generic (and also make it static).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `LinkedStackIterator` class is generic, when it refers to `Item` it means a different type to the `Item` used in your outer classes. One solution is to change `LinkedStackIterator` so it is not generic, i.e. change:

```
class LinkedStackIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item>{
```

to

```
class LinkedStackIterator implements Iterator<Item>{
```

Side note: it can be quite confusing to Java programmers to see generic type variables given meaningful names like `Item`. You may wish to consider renaming this to something more expected like `T`.

Comment: I will follow the convention as suggested by you. Thanks :).

Comment: If it's right, mark as correct answer bro @pradeep.